# Skipping the Java tests in Jhipster using Maven for build

Tags: java, maven, unit-testing, testing, jhipster

I am using Jhipster to build a webapp.

I modified some of stuff at the backend of the java.
Now,when i run it through the maven it is also compling the test cases which came with the jhipster generator and i don't want to modify them
instead want to skip them.

When in run maven by

```
./mvnw -DskipTests=true
```

It is not skipping those tests.
I have tried cleaning and re compiling but still no effect.

Could anyone Tell me how to skip those tests.

Comment: You are seeing expected behavior. `skipTests` skips test execution but still compiles them. Use `maven.test.skip` if you want to also skip test compilation.

Comment: This will skip ALL the tests, even the ones you write by your own..

Answer (score 7):

try this cmd :  \mvnw.cmd -Pprod package -DskipTests

Answer (score 2):

The mvnw wrapper supplied with jHipster doesn't run the tests anyway so -DskipTests wont do anything. To compile and run your project without compiling tests do:

mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true spring-boot:run

Answer (score 0):

Use the below command:

mvn clean compile -Dmaven.test.skip=true